# 'py.test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pytest, pep8

I started learning python recently and I know my problem may not be sth complicated. I issued below command from my Windows cmd to install pytest framework and its required dependencies

`py -3 -m pip install pytest`

and then issued:
`py -3 -m pip install pytest-pep8`

to install pep8 plug-in and required dependencies. Both commands were done successfully.

But when I want to run pytest by `py.test --pep8 exp1.py` command; I get mentioned error.

any ideas?

Comment: please add error in question to well understand your problem thanks.

Comment: what about `py -3 -m pytest` instead of `py.test` ?

Comment: what @alkasm says seems to work. test session starts but can't collect item(i.e. my program) and i receive about 15 lines error that i don't exactly understand the problem.

Answer (score 17):

Getting the same problem, but it has been solved with the below command

```
python -m pytest
```

Comment: python -m pytest filename.py 
will run for specific file

Answer (score 1):

The error you got seems to be due to improper installation of pytest or due to use of *py.test* in your command.

First, check whether you have pytest installed in your environment. Open command prompt and use the below command,

```
pytest --version
```

You must get an output like,

```
pytest 6.0.2
```

If you get an output similar to the above result that means you have installed pytest successfully.

Now, navigate to the folder where your script *exp1.py* is using **cd** command in cmd and  try running your script as follows,

```
pytest --pep8 exp1.py
```

Comment: I was thinking the same way when i saw the output. But pytest and pep8 plug-in were installed successfully and are avaible in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\site-packages\pytest\ address in my pc. But when i issue "pytest --version" command, i get the output i mentioned as my question name in this page.

Comment: Okay. Then try creating a virtual environment.  Use these commands:  **pip install virtualenvwrapper-win**  and **mkvirtualenv myVirtualEnv**

Comment: The command prompt must now be like:  **(myVirtualEnv) C:\Users\<UserName>**

Comment: Now, reinstall pytest and pep8 using the same commands you used before and now, try running your script by navigating to the folder where your script is, using **cd** command and then using **pytest --pep8 exp1.py**

Comment: Also, note that before installing pytest and pep8 in the virtual environment, you must consider uninstalling them from the global environment (your normal *cmd*). Use the following commands to uninstall: **py -3 -m pip uninstall pytest** and **py -3 -m pip uninstall pytest-pep8**

Answer (score 1):

i am learning python with head first python book,
i have been trying to use pytest module but was,
not working and even search online everywhere
but i could not find the solution the problem but
some how, i manage to figure it out.
so here's the solution
the current version of pytest is version 6.2.2 unfortunately if use it with
`py.test --pep8`
it will not work because it has been deprecated the simple solution is to use this
version
`pip install pytest==2.9.1`
and when it's successfully installed when you tried
with the
`py.test --pep8`
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

So basically this msg comes in cmd when you haven't installed pytest package.

Steps to solve.

open cmd type :  **pip install pytest**

then open the dir where your test scripts are availabe type pytest and hit enter, issue is resolved.

Answer (score -2):

to run pytest along with geting output status in terminal run this in terminal:

```
pytest -v -s filename.py
```

if the file is not present, run this in the current directory:

```
pytest -v -s <filepath>/filename.py
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Still the same output: "'pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."